# Firefox not downloading files correctly

Tags: php, firefox

When i try to download  a file from my website using chrome it downloads fine also when i use download manager on Firefox it also download fine however when i try to use the Firefox downloader it screw up the file name , e.g. file name " game god mode.zip" , When i download the file with Firefox it only show "game" and i have to rename the file to add ".zip" after downloading to get it to open ,Does this problem happen because i have a problem with my PHP code ? because it works fine except on Firefox .

Comment: Millions of people use Firefox but you think the problem is with the browser and not your code? Audacious.

Comment: `(One in a million)` =>>>

Comment: How are you sending the file name in PHP? [Different browsers parse the `Content-Disposition` header in different (incompatible) ways](http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/).

Comment: Shouldn't that be "no code = no `answer`"? @Dagon ;-)

Comment: code make question, question required for answer, vodka required for  Moscow-mule, Moscow-mule required for life

Comment: `*Raises glass to cheer*` @Dagon Hops on mule, runs away for life =>>>

Comment: Why is it that our comments always get deleted? We can't have anymore fun in this place! @Dagon lol people are just too serious.

Comment: @Fred-ii- its my boss, he thinks just because he pays me i should be working

Comment: HAH, the nerve of him!! Now, if your boss were a "she", well then, that would be a different story. @Dagon ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any file that you want to rely on the behaviour of shouldn't have spaces in the name.  Change the name to game_god_mode.zip.

Comment: I used str_replace(" ","_",$filename); and the problem is solved! ,Thank you so much!.